# Regex to remove everything after a new line

Tags: regex, line, yahoo-pipes

It seems simple, but I don't get it to work.
I wan't to delete everything after something..... but I only get to delete line 1.
example :

1. this is line 1
2. this is line 2
3. this is line 3
4. this is line 4

I get to delete line 1, but not 2,3 and 4.

Some tips ?

More information :
I tried to do this in [Yahoo pipes](http://s1377.photobucket.com/user/John_van_der_Linden/media/yahoopipes_zpsc16a2adf.jpg.html).

I like to delete everything after : `</div></a></div>`

Comment: can you post your regex? are you using multiline option with ^$ qualifiers?

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
\n.*
```

That should match anything after a new line.
I used the following command in vim and it deleted lines 2, 3, and 4.

```
:%s/\n.*//g
```

I think you need to provide more details like the tool you are using, etc.

Comment: I have add more inormation. Thanks for the quick reply!